# Division between column with pandas: TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have no clue what went wrong.
Create a dataframe with a 2d list, other than first 3 columns ['year', 'month', 'site'], everything else is float64. df1.dtypes proves that.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(raw_data)
df1.columns = ['year', 'month', 'site','imp', 'click', 'cost_ad', 'cpc',
               'conv_value', 'conv_count', 'value_per_conv',
               'cost_good', 'cost_ship', 'cost_ad', 'profit']

print(df1.dtypes)
df1["click"] = pd.to_numeric(df1["click"])   # <<== tried this, nope 
df1['cpc'] = df1['click'] / df1['cost_ad']
```

But the division at the end throws me:

```
joined_ndarray, lidx, ridx = libjoin.outer_join_indexer(sv, ov)
File "pandas/_libs/join.pyx", line 575, in pandas._libs.join.outer_join_indexer
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

I'm not even using '<' or comparing.

Further more, without adding the column, this works with no error.
df1[6] = df1[4] / df1[5]

Comment: Does `pd.to_numeric(df1["cost_ad"])` run without problems?

Comment: @enke found it .... I have two 'cost_ad' column. to_numeric will throw me: TypeError: arg must be a list, tuple, 1-d array, or Series. Thanks for the suggestion. I need to find a way to prevent duplicate columns name in the future. ToT